# Minor preview bug - mixed case HtTp urls display in preview but disappear from 'live' post

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, hyperlinks

Here is an example:

`http://www.google.com` -> http://www.google.com

`Http://www.google.com`->

If you edit this question you'll see that both urls display in the preview - but the second one mixed-case which is not standards-compliant is (correctly IMO) eliminated in the 'live' version.

Comment: How bizarre. HtTp://google.co.uk ...

Comment: When I read the title of the question I thought it an unlikely scenario, but with only the first letter capitalized, I can see how this could happen.

Comment: @Obed, yes it did happen too on dba.se. I used HtTp in the title as I was worried that Http would not be processed as odd by the average human brain. Mine didn't for a while though admittedly my brain is a little below average :-)

Comment: The client-side sanitizer uses case-insensitive regular expressions where the server-side one doesn't, which is [easily fixed](https://code.google.com/r/tmslft-pagedown/source/detail?r=bf3e1b1322b895d268cc6d4bbe19b841b8e7f7cc), but there may have been good reason for that. Even then, the client-side sanitizer leaves behind the URL as plaintext, so I'm unsure what the server-side is doing that causes it to be removed completely...

Comment: @TimStone: autolinking in our Markdown versions happens by enclosing bare links in `<http://anglebrackets>` if they aren't, and then converting links in angle brackets to actual links. Since the server doesn't consider it a valid link, the `<Http://foobar>` stays as it is, and to the sanitizer, it looks like an HTML tag that gets killed.

Comment: @balpha Ohhhh, that makes sense. I see the difference in `DoAutoLinks` now. :)

Comment: The [RFC says](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) *For resiliency, programs interpreting URLs should treat upper case letters as equivalent to lower case in scheme names (e.g., allow "HTTP" as well as "http").* -- so I guess it's okay to allow mixed case. Of course we should do it consistently.